# @Autowired dependency injection not occurring in junit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot to bootstrap a spring-data-neo4j application. My unit tests (with no dependencies injected) run fine, but when I try to run an integration test with an `@Autowired` dependency on a `@Service`-annotated class, it's failing on a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

It seems like the context isn't being loaded in the unit test for some reason, but I've annotated the test with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)` - is there something else I need to do here?

**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.foo.bar")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "net.foo.bar.repo")
public class AppConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public AppConfig() {
        setBasePackage("net.foo.bar");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(filePath);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Service class:**

```
package net.foo.bar.core.service
@Service
public class PostService implements EntityService<PostDAO,Post> {

    @Autowired
    Neo4jTemplate template;
    //...
    //don't think anything else here is relevant
}
```

**Test class:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
public class PostTests {
    @Autowired
    PostService postService;

    @Test
    public void someTest(){ 
        postService.doSomething();
        //...
    }

 }
```

**Stack trace:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'net.foo.bar.PostTests': ....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.foo.bar.core.service.PostService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 31 common frames omitted
```

**Update:**

As a workaround, rather than autowiring my service directly, I tried autowiring a reference to the `ApplicationContext` and instantiating my service through a call to `getBeanOfType()` in my `setUp()` method:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Epublic.class)
public class PostTests {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    PostService service; 

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        service = ctx.getBean("postServiceImpl", PostService.class);
    }
}
```

This is working, but I feel like I'm hitting the target but missing the point here...

Comment: The bean id ("postServiceImpl") in your workaround doesn't match the bean id in your `@Service` ("postService"). So I suspect something else is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `basePackages` for `@ComponentScan`. You have only for `NeojConfiguration`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "net.foo.bar" })
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "net.foo.bar.repo")
public class AppConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public AppConfig() {
        setBasePackage("net.foo.bar");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(filePath);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: gahhh... sorry, this was a rookie move on my part, but that was an input error. I do have the base package specified in my real code. +1 though for confirming that this is still necessary when `setBasePackage()` is called in `Neo4jConfiguration`, though - I wasn't sure about that.